# wrong checksum(sha256) when copying from exfat samsung t7 touch external ssd to android(galaxy s10)

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I bought a Samsung t7 touch SSD(1TB), it works just fine with my computer. but when I copy some files(200MB<) from the SSD to my phone which is a galaxy s10 the files get corrupted, and sometimes the SSD automatically disconnects itself from the phone while copying files.

I use the USBc to USBc cable that comes in the box.
Strange thing is that when it use the USBa to USBc cable in SSD's box and a USBa to USBc adapter that came with my phone, it is ok, but transfer speed is really slow.

By the way the USBc to USBc cable is not faulty cause I tested the cable with the SSD and my PC and it works fine, meaning all the files copy fast and with no problem regarding checksums.

Comment: probably related to MTP bug

Comment: @alecxs This question if I understand correctly seems to use the SSD via USB OTG. Thus there is no PC and MTP involved.

Comment: If you use the USBa workaround how much speed si "slow"? USB 2.0 speed ~30 MB/sec or USB 3.0 speed 500MB/sec? Have you tried different USBc cables? Have you experienced battery problems with your phone? More speed means much higher power consumption of SSD+phone, may be the battery does not supplay enough and the bits degrade.

Comment: when I use the USBc to USBc cable in the box connecting my phone directly to the SSD the problem exists, but when I use USBa to USBc adapter with USBa to USBc cable it's ok.